# Dotnet maui error when i restore my project NETSDK1139

Tags: .net, maui, .net-maui

When i run “dotnet restore”
It shows me this error and I am using windows 10

> NETSDK1139: The target platform identifier ios was not recognized.

Answer (score 2):

Since maui is still in preview the best place where to look is the official repos, it has been reported in https://github.com/dotnet/net6-mobile-samples/issues/47 and https://github.com/dotnet/net6-mobile-samples/issues/67

> you must create the EnableWorkloadResolver.sentinel file (as described in the README), or alternatively export MSBuildEnableWorkloadResolver=true for the same effect.
> So as mentioned in the linked issues, you either:

- Follow the [readme](https://github.com/dotnet/net6-mobile-samples#readme) file to include the sentinel file required.
- Or install the Android workload as well, it will include sentinel for you.

Comment: I'm getting `NETSDK1139: The target platform identifier maccatalyst was not recognized.` error on the latest version. What to do? :(

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/1795 here is the issue btw.

Answer (score 1):

Experiencing another workload problem a couple of years ago, I set the environment variable `MSBuildEnableWorkloadResolve` to `false` and forgot it. After struggling with the NETSDK1139 error message for some time I finally decided to go look into my envvars. And yes, a variable with that name stands out pretty neatly when you look for a solution. After deleting the `MSBuildEnableWorkloadResolver` envvar and restarting VS2022, everything worked just fine.